# tracking multiple objects of the same color

Tags: python, opencv

I'm able to do object tracking of different colors just by applying various thresholds. (for example.. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=njab2bBps6U&feature=player_embedded)

However, I've been unable to determine a solution for tracking multiple objects of the same color.

I'm not looking for code to solve my problems, more just trying to figure out what the standard method isis and I'll figure it out myself.

I'm using opencv with its python bindings.

Comment: So single object (of a particular colour) is clearly trivial. For multiple object tracking the situation depends on the objects being tracked and whether you have to worry about issues such as merging/splitting (and or occlusion). It sounds like for your scenario (from the video) you'll be dealing with just a few objects and they won't be moving very fast, relative to their separation. In that regime you can probably get away with Nearest Neighbor tracking . Things quickly get more complicated once that doesn't work - but I'd start there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not very hard. Here's algorithm:

1. In the first (or some) frame find positions of all objects with the same color. It seems that you know how to do that.
2. Using [Lucas–Kanade method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Kanade_method) and it's [implementation in OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#cv-calcopticalflowpyrlk) track all these objects in videostream (second and next frames).

Here's [example (video)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zNqCNMefyV8) of using it.

Here's [sample code](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/lkdemo.cpp?rev=4118) (cpp, not python).