# Multiple Same Color object tracking (Python3 Opencv)

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0, hsv

I am seriously struggling here. I'm using open cv2 and python3. [tracking multiple objects of the same color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634695/tracking-multiple-objects-of-the-same-color) this question is the exact same one I'm asking. But the pages are out of date and the links don't work anymore. I can't find anything else online about it. I can track multiple colors (red object, green object, a blue object, etc) However I cannot for the life of me figure out how to track two red objects.

```
# import the necessary packages
from collections import deque
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video",
    help="path to the (optional) video file")
ap.add_argument("-b", "--buffer", type=int, default=64,
    help="max buffer size")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
# define the lower and upper boundaries of the "green"
# ball in the HSV color space, then initialize the
# list of tracked points
greenLower = (29, 86, 6)
greenUpper = (64, 255, 255)
pts = deque(maxlen=args["buffer"])

# if a video path was not supplied, grab the reference
# to the webcam
if not args.get("video", False):
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# otherwise, grab a reference to the video file
else:
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(args["video"])
# keep looping
while True:
    # grab the current frame
    (grabbed, frame) = camera.read()

    # if we are viewing a video and we did not grab a frame,
    # then we have reached the end of the video
    if args.get("video") and not grabbed:
        break

    # resize the frame, blur it, and convert it to the HSV
    # color space
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=600)
    # blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (11, 11), 0)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # construct a mask for the color "green", then perform
    # a series of dilations and erosions to remove any small
    # blobs left in the mask
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, greenLower, greenUpper)
    mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=2)
    mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=2)
    # find contours in the mask and initialize the current
    # (x, y) center of the ball
    cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
    center = None

    # only proceed if at least one contour was found
    if len(cnts) > 0:
        # find the largest contour in the mask, then use
        # it to compute the minimum enclosing circle and
        # centroid
        c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
```

I figured that in the line above this one that reads "c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)" I could simply find the second largest circle and use that one, but once again. I couldn't find anything online about how to do this.

```
        ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
        M = cv2.moments(c)
        center = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))

        # only proceed if the radius meets a minimum size
        if radius > 10:
            # draw the circle and centroid on the frame,
            # then update the list of tracked points
            cv2.circle(frame, (int(x), int(y)), int(radius),
                (0, 255, 255), 2)
            cv2.circle(frame, center, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)

    # update the points queue
    pts.appendleft(center)
```